# API Яндекс карт. Построение маршрута минуя область полигона

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть яндекс карта Москвы. На ней сделал 3 полигона: Садовое кальцо, ТТК и МКАД.
Мне нужно, чтобы построеный маршрут не проходил, например, через полигон Садовое кольцо. Естествено внутри полигонов точек откуда, куда и транзитных нет.

Как-то можно это сделать?

Много информации перерыл, но никак не могу найти как строить маршруты, чтобы они не проходили через палигоны.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Если маршрут должен строить Яндекс, вы это никак физически не ограничите. Маршрутизация сервиса использует собственные графы дорог и алгоритмы упрощения задач. Если алгоритм решит использовать дорожные графы внутри полигона, потому что это выгодней, он это сделает.

Можете лишь добавлять множество via-точек в объезд полигонов для каждого маршрута. Но сделать это автоматом, а не вручную, едва ли получится - потребуется проверять все узловые точки маршрута на попадание в полигон и как-то рассчитывать создание via-точек рядом с ним.

Если тема будет востребована, и в Яндекс.Карты будут регулярно поступать от пользователей просьбы реализовать подобный алгоритм, скорее всего разработчики придумают и добавят возможность строить маршруты с огибанием самых популярных территорий, на которые распространяются некоторые ограничения передвижения.